# How to Structure Mongo Database for REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, database, nosql

I'm writing a REST API with Mongo and was intrigued by the whole document modeling strategy. It seems like a very divisive issue where people say to denormalize first, then normalize or vice-versa.

I'm interested to see how the resource structure of a REST api influences the structure of a document-based db. It seems like with a REST api resource structure, it almost makes sense to have separate collections for everything (i.e. locations, tenants, transactions) although this seems like it would be working against one of Mongo's benefits.

My question is how would you model the resources of a REST api in a NoSQL (specifically Mongo) document database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, there are many ways, depending on what you want to optimize on.
Generally, the defining of your document schemas and separation of collections will depend on what your specific use cases for the documents are - how will you consume your data?

One big concept to remember, is that "Joins" between collections are costly - basically you're getting a foreign key from one collection and doing a whole other lookup in another collection, which is why de-normalization generally helps performance - if it matches your use cases. This is where MongoDB has the potential to shine, although in the future if your requirements change, your document structures could potentially need to change dramatically.

A second key consideration, is the MongoDB document size limit - roughly 16MB last time I checked. 
Take your classic blog website example, with a blog posts collection. We can choose to store comments as subdocuments, as an array in the post document. This way, you could have a rest API for /posts/postID, returning you the post document without having to do any "joins" or lookups in other collections for comments and so forth. But then you run into problems, if you have posts with humongous amounts of comments on it, so in that case, you would have to normalize your data by separating out comments into another collection.

So, speed / ease of retrieval from the database and the flexibility of your document storage - should you need to change a document's schema structure for the future, are two major considerations you should think about as you plan a project API out.

Ask yourself, how does document/collection X going to be used? When would you need to retrieve data from it? If one resource *tenants* has a "parent resource" *location*, and accessing location is the only time you actually need tenants, then by all means you could potentially design the storage of tenants into the schema of location. But if you need to be able to query tenants by themselves, then you probably want to break tenants out into their own collection. So there's no right or wrong ways to go about it, just base your planning on how you plan to consume your data!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed reply. It confirms what I was thinking. Originally I was going to have a structure such as Locations -> Tenants -> Transactions, but once I understood that we would need to be CRUDing on each of those resources, and would never need to grab two resources together (i.e. Locations won't need to be retrieved with Tenants) I was thinking of splitting them up into separate collections.

My one concern is that if I'm separating the resources into collections, I wouldn't be leveraging one of Mongo's benefits in eliminating joins, and storing parent ref ids.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. It's ok if you have references to documents, between collections. If you plan on using MongoDB, you don't necessarily need to milk all the advantages out of it, only to make life harder for yourself when you write your queries and so forth. Keep in mind, MongoDB also has aggregation pipelines and more advanced features, that can support querying subdocuments, it's just more work!

Comment: Great. The one weird thing though is that if I have references to documents between collections, and the referenced document is deleted, I'll have to remember to delete that reference (and possibly the child document that contains the reference).

Comment: Yup, it's all on you (on the programming side) to ensure you update or remove the appropriate documents when another is modified or deleted. There is no enforcing of references in MongoDB.